# WPF Binding Converter does not run when Property Path is null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, converters

I have this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool? Accepted { get; set; } = true;
}
```

... and this ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyClass MyClass => null;
}
```

... and this View:

```
<MyControl.Resources>
    <mynamespace:RedColorWhenNullConverter x:Key="RedColorWhenNullConverter" />
</MyControl.Resources>
<Rectangle
    Height="100"
    Width="100"
    Fill="{Binding MyClass.Accepted, Converter={StaticResource RedColorWhenNullConverter}}"
/>
```

... and this ValueConverter:

```
public class RedColorWhenNullConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }

    {...}
}
```

When the view model returns null for `MyClass` property, the converter does not run at all. I was expecting it to run with the value `null`.

If the `DataContext` of the view is `MyClass` and the binding was directly to the `Accepted` property like this: `{Binding Accpected, ...`, and `Accepted` property returns `null` the converter runs.

How is this any different from the binding chain `MyClass.Accepted`? And is there any workarounds for this issue?

Does there exist a null-conditional operator for xaml as in `C#`? Would be nice to do this `{Binding MyClass?.Accepted, ...`.

Comment: In this case `Fill="{Binding MyClass.Accepted, Converter={StaticResource RedColorWhenNullConverter}}"` it throws NRE, make sense to use `FallbackValue` or `TargetNullValue`

Answer (score 0):

The Binding Converter is supposed to convert the value of the Binding's source property to a value that is assignable to the target property.

If the value of the source property can not be evaluated, the Converter can't be called.

You may add `FallbackValue=Red` to the Binding, but the Converter is still not called.

Alternatively do not use a Converter at all, but a Style with DataTriggers and a default value for the `Fill` property:

```
<Rectangle Height="100" Width="100">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyClass.Accepted}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyClass.Accepted}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but my real problem is totally different from the example. I need the converter to be run, even when `MyClass` is `null` to be able to fix my real problem.

Comment: "*If the value of the source property can not be evaluated, the Converter can't be called*" - you can not convert something that does not exist.

Comment: You may however write `Fill="{Binding MyClass, ...}"` and let the converter convert a `MyClass` value instead of a `bool?`

Comment: You could use `Value="{x:Null}"` as well as true and false. But that is just by the by